# InvalidToken using SharePoint v2.0 REST API

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, sharepoint-api, sharepoint-rest-api

I am trying to make **CRUD operations of the TermStore** using the v2.0 REST API. But I am having problems with the token. *I can generate the token correctly* but when I try to use it, for example on a GET call to get the groups of the TermStore it simply appears the next error

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "unauthenticated",
        "innerError": {
            "code": "invalidToken"
        },
        "message": "The provided token is invalid"
    }
}
```

I gave **maximum permissions** to the app, because maybe it was a problem of not enough permissions
I've tried giving both types of permissions, *Application* and *Delegated*

[Application Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9o0jX.png)

[Delegated Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lDyvz.png)

Obviously **I have granted admin consent**.

This is how I fetch the token:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
myHeaders.append("Cookie", "fpc=YOUR_FPC_COOKIE; stsservicecookie=estsfd; x-ms-gateway-slice=estsfd");


var formdata = new FormData();
formdata.append("grant_type", "client_credentials");
formdata.append("client_id", "myID");
formdata.append("client_secret", "mySecret");
formdata.append("scope", "https://contoso.sharepoint.com/.default");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: myHeaders,
  body: new URLSearchParams(formdata),
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://login.microsoftonline.com/myTenantID/oauth2/v2.0/token", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

It works fine, It returns me a token that expires in one hour (obviously *I refresh the token every hour*, I still do it manually because first i want to have it working well).

But when using the token appears the error that I previously mentioned. This is the complete GET call:

```
var myHeaders = new Headers();
myHeaders.append("Authorization", "Bearer verylongtoken");

var requestOptions = {
  method: 'GET',
  headers: myHeaders,
  redirect: 'follow'
};

fetch("https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/v2.1/termstore/groups", requestOptions)
  .then(response => response.text())
  .then(result => console.log(result))
  .catch(error => console.log('error', error));
```

I've searched similar questions like

[Invalid Audience URI error Service to Service application, onedrive for business](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35583923/invalid-audience-uri-error-service-to-service-application-onedrive-for-business)

or

[Sharepoint Online REST API with Azure AD v2.0 authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55106609/sharepoint-online-rest-api-with-azure-ad-v2-0-authentication)

and

[How to get access token without sign-up or sign-in to web app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56393182/how-to-get-access-token-without-sign-up-or-sign-in-to-web-app)

I've tried all the solutions but nothing.

I also have created an **Application ID URI** but doesn't work neither. I don't know what else to try

Should I try to work with the **Microsoft Graph API** instead of the SharePoint API? I know that in the past you couldn't work with Term Store but now the permission *TermStore.ReadWrite.All* exist, so If you think is a viable option let me now.

I hope I have explained well,

Thank you,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I try to work with the Microsoft Graph API instead of the SharePoint API?

Yes, very much so. For example, for the request in your example, you'd use [List termStore groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/termstore-list-groups?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

Comment: Thank you for answering! But It seems that is not supported for the Application type... 
I want to make an app that doesn't require any kind of user account, I really don't understand why the token doesn't work well for the SharePoint API...

Comment: Some SharePoint APIs require using a certificate when obtaining a token, and actively reject tokens obtained with a client secret. You may want to try that. But it might be that SharePoint just doesn't support app-only access for this API at all, on any API.

Comment: I didn't know about that extra step with certificates, but well I've managed to get it working with an app-only access despite Microsoft telling is not supported with Graph soo that's it. Thank you!

Comment: Good to know you got it to work. That said, do be careful about taking a dependent on an API, or on the way in which you use an API, when it's not documented. If a certain pattern is not documented (or if it's explicitly documented as unsupported), you should assume there is a high risk of it being disabled or broken at some point in the future.